# Get specific element's values of selected row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with two rows, at the end of each row there is cancel button, and when i click on cancel button it should return the specific column data of the clicked row, but it always return the value from 1st row, I have tried but nothing happens.
What I specifically need that, lets say I have a column with name Book Code which is hidden, if user click on cancel button (from first row) it should return the book code value from first row, and if user click on cancel button (from Second row) it should return the book code value from Second row.

Here is my code sample:

**HTML**

```
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">CANCEL</div>
          <div class="divTableCell" >BOOKING #</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ROUTE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">SEAT #</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DATE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">TIME</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1"><p onclick="cancel_reservation();"> CANCEL </p></div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_code"                       style="display:none;">111</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_terminal" style="display:none;">222222222</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">0000</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">RWP_LHR</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">900</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">12</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">26th May, 2016</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">2335</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1"><p onclick="cancel_reservation();"> CANCEL </p></div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_code"                       style="display:none;">aaaa</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_terminal" style="display:none;">bbbb</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">0000</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">RWP_LHR</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">900</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">12</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">26th May, 2016</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">2335</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
        color: #fff;
        display: table-header-group;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        width:30%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.cancel_reservation = function() {

    alert("YES");
    var book_code_call = $("#book_code").text();
    var book_terminal_call = $("#book_terminal").text();
        alert(book_code_call);
        alert(book_terminal_call);

 }
```

Any idea how to achieve what I want ?
Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7xwgtcop/10/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get values of columns for a selected row through jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636518/how-to-get-values-of-columns-for-a-selected-row-through-jquery)

Comment: you have double id´s...

use the keyword this, then select this parent an search for the child´s of this parent...

Comment: add the diffrernt id for each cancel button and call button click event using that id...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**

Pass this to argument in click function

**Second**

Use [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent row and than [.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function to find element you wanted to get values

Please find below snippet fore more info...

```js
window.cancel_reservation = function(e) {
  
  var book_code_call  = $(e).closest(".divTableRow").find("#book_code").text();
  var book_terminal_call = $(e).closest(".divTableRow").find("#book_terminal").text();
  alert(book_code_call);
  alert(book_terminal_call);
  
 }
```

```css
.divTable{
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top:20px;
  }
  .divTableRow {
   display: table-row;
  }
  .divTableHeading {
   background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
   color: #fff;
   display: table-header-group;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
   border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   width:30%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
   border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .divTableHeading {
   background-color: #EEE;
   display: table-header-group;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  .divTableFoot {
   background-color: #EEE;
   display: table-footer-group;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  .divTableBody {
   display: table-row-group;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">CANCEL</div>
    <div class="divTableCell" >BOOKING #</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">ROUTE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">SEAT #</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">DATE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">TIME</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
   <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1"><p onclick="cancel_reservation(this);"> CANCEL </p></div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_code"                       style="display:none;">111</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_terminal" style="display:none;">222222222</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">0000</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">RWP_LHR</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">900</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">12</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">26th May, 2016</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">2335</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1"><p onclick="cancel_reservation(this);"> CANCEL </p></div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_code"                       style="display:none;">aaaa</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_terminal" style="display:none;">bbbb</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">0000</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">RWP_LHR</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">900</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">12</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">26th May, 2016</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">2335</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

Please find Below snippet as well...

Add a class `cancel` and bind click method on a class using [.On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
 $(".cancel").on("click",function(){
   var book_code_call  = $(this).closest(".divTableRow").find("#book_code").text();
    var book_terminal_call = $(this).closest(".divTableRow").find("#book_terminal").text();
  alert(book_code_call);
  alert(book_terminal_call);
 });
```

```css
.divTable{
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top:20px;
  }
  .divTableRow {
   display: table-row;
  }
  .divTableHeading {
   background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
   color: #fff;
   display: table-header-group;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
   border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   width:30%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
   border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .divTableHeading {
   background-color: #EEE;
   display: table-header-group;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  .divTableFoot {
   background-color: #EEE;
   display: table-footer-group;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  .divTableBody {
   display: table-row-group;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">CANCEL</div>
    <div class="divTableCell" >BOOKING #</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">ROUTE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">SEAT #</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">DATE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">TIME</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
   <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1"><p class="cancel"> CANCEL </p></div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_code"                       style="display:none;">111</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_terminal" style="display:none;">222222222</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">0000</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">RWP_LHR</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">900</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">12</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">26th May, 2016</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">2335</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1"><p class="cancel"> CANCEL </p></div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_code"                       style="display:none;">aaaa</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="book_terminal" style="display:none;">bbbb</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">0000</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">RWP_LHR</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">900</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">12</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">26th May, 2016</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">2335</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As an alternative you can also make it work applying the context of the current buttons clicked using `onclick="cancel_reservation.call(this);"` and then use the local `this` context without the need for a paremeter `var $row = $(this).closest('.divTableRow');` This will also make the function easier transferable if you ever decide to bind it through JavaScript instead of inline :)

Comment: @Fran Yes i'm totally agree with you there are many ways to do the same thing though anyways thanx